# Smarty 3 Exit Tag

Tags: php, smarty

IN Smarty 3  we are using

1 - `{break}` to break; for continue; keyword

2-  `{continue}`  is used for `continue;` keyword I have written custom plugin for exit tag as which is same as `break`

```
<?php
    /*
    *   Modified for exit tag
    */

    function smarty_compiler_exit( $contents, &$smarty ) {
       return 'exit;';
    }
?>
```

BUT WHEN I USE `{exit}` it gives output as `:- exit; only not working as php exit keyword`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: don't use reserved keyword of php as exit that not work and make error

Comment: @sectus {exit} is not working in smarty 3

Comment: This is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `return`?

compiler.return.php

```
 <?php 
    function smarty_compiler_return($tag_arg, &$smarty) { 
    return "<?php return;?>"; 
    } 
    ?>
```

So when we call it like `{return}` within a TPL, it returns the flow to PHP.